# Mongoose Model.find always returning an empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am using mongoose with next.js to access pre existing collection.

mongoose model.find() is always returning an empty array but the collection is not empty.

here is my model code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ArtistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({});

module.exports = mongoose.models.Artist || mongoose.model('Artist', ArtistSchema, 'artists' );
```

here is the api code

```
export default async (req, res) => {
    const { method } = req;

    switch (method) {
        case 'GET':
            try {
               
                const artists = await Artist.find({});

                res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: artists})
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(400).json({ success: false });
            }
            break;
        case 'POST':
            try {
                const artist = await Artist.create(req.body);

                res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: artist })
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(400).json({ success: false });
            }
            break;
        default:
            res.status(400).json({ success: false });
            break;
    }
}
```

here is the screenshot of collection which is not empty
[artists collection screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIsT4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the `const artists` to get your `output`.

Answer (score 0):

first, I need to know if you have connected with mongo DB atlas, if not do this in your api `/index.js`, you can get `YOUR_MONGO_DB_URL` at [mongoDB  site](https://account.mongodb.com/account/login), then require the model in `/index.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect(YOUR_MONGO_DB_URL, {useUnifiedTopology:true, useNewUrlParser:true, autoIndex:false}).then(() => {
    console.log("sucsess");
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("error:"+err)

require(YOUR_FILE_PATH)
})
```

And in you model file you should define the indexes like how was done below just for example

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ArtistSchema = new Schema({
     name: {
        type : String,
        require: true,
    },
    email: {
        type : String,
        unique : true,
        reqquired : true,
        lowercase : true,
    },
    password : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        select: false,
    },
    createdAt : {
        type : Date,
        default : Date.now,
    }
});

mongoose.model('Artist', ArtistSchema)
```